# Как верстать в Joomla макеты?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Здравствуйте. Нужно подверстать макет оформления покупок (плагин OnePage Checkout), вот только не знаю, как это лучше сделать. Думал, что лучше всего найти стили этого плагина и их изменить, но вот где они и как их найти? Как ещё можно подверстать макет оформления покупок? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько помню файлы стилей для данного плагина должны быть в 
`plugins\system\onepage_generic\cart\`

Comment: Я почему-то не вижу папку onepage_generic

Comment: а просто папку onepage ?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/qnZf4CbW3EWt8i вот скриншот

Comment: а что в папке opc ? или opccart ? но самый простой метод можно на сайте, конкретно на элементе нажать правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать Инспект, в открывшемся дебагере просто посмотреть путь к файлу css который обеспечивает стили данного элемента

Comment: тоже нет, может она по другому называется. я подумал opc и т. д., но в них нету папки cart. кстати я починил добавление товаров без перезагрузки (без той ошибки), дело не в ошибки

Comment: я рад за корзину ) можете сами и ответить на свой заданный вопрос, тем самым, другим с такой же проблемой может поможет.

Comment: а найти css файл методом дебага - не судьба? посмотрели в дебаге браузера ?

Comment: да уже смотрю, осталось найти нужный